# In REVTex 4.2 aapm template, including a full address with forced line brakes causes full justification. Fix?

Tags: revtex

I'm using REVTeX 4.2 as a base template for creating internal documents at work (not for journal submission, I just really like the format!), and I'm having issues with the aapm template.

I want to add my full work address within the \affiliation{} environment, but when I do, it screws up the formatting. See below:

Without full address:

[image: Without full address]

```
\documentclass[aapm,reprint]{revtex4-2}
\begin{document}
\title[ABC-XXXXXX Fancy Paper Title]{Fancy Paper Title}
\author{M.Y. Name}
\email[]{m\_y.email@abc.com}
\affiliation{
ABC Company%\\
%123 Road Ln\\
%Fancy City, MI 48123\\
%United States
}
\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
Fancy abstract.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle 
\section{First Section}
Stuff. Blah blah blah, etc etc etc.
\section{Second Section}
More stuff
\subsection{Look, a subsection!}
Even more stuff!
\end{document}
```

With full address

[image: With full address]

```
\documentclass[aapm,reprint]{revtex4-2}
\begin{document}
\title[ABC-XXXXXX Fancy Paper Title]{Fancy Paper Title}
\author{M.Y. Name}
\email[]{m\_y.email@abc.com}
\affiliation{
ABC Company\\
123 Road Ln\\
Fancy City, MI 48123\\
United States
}
\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
Fancy abstract.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle 
\section{First Section}
Stuff. Blah blah blah, etc etc etc.
\section{Second Section}
More stuff
\subsection{Look, a subsection!}
Even more stuff!
\end{document}
```

I've tried using flushleft, but it also messed up the formatting:

[image: With full address and flushleft]

```
\documentclass[aapm,reprint]{revtex4-2}
\begin{document}
\title[ABC-XXXXXX Fancy Paper Title]{Fancy Paper Title}
\author{M.Y. Name}
\email[]{m\_y.email@abc.com}
\affiliation{
\begin{flushleft}
ABC Company\\
123 Road Ln\\
Fancy City, MI 48123\\
United States
\end{flushleft}
}
\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
Fancy abstract.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle 
\section{First Section}
Stuff. Blah blah blah, etc etc etc.
\section{Second Section}
More stuff
\subsection{Look, a subsection!}
Even more stuff!
\end{document}
```

Any advice on how to correct this? I'm totally ok with going into the base classes and modifying them, if that will accomplish the desired result, I just don't really know where to begin with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way it to use a minipage.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aapm,reprint]{revtex4-2}
\begin{document}
    \title[ABC-XXXXXX Fancy Paper Title]{Fancy Paper Title}
    \author{M.Y. Name}
    \email[]{m\_y.email@abc.com}
    \affiliation{%
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
            ABC Company \\
            123 Road Ln\\
            Fancy City, MI 48123\\
            United States
        \end{minipage}
    }
    \date{\today}
    \begin{abstract}
        Fancy abstract.
    \end{abstract}
    \maketitle 
    \section{First Section}
    Stuff. Blah blah blah, etc etc etc.
    \section{Second Section}
    More stuff
    \subsection{Look, a subsection!}
    Even more stuff!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not familiar with the `aapm` option, I imagine the expectation is to put the address as comma-separated, as `\affiliation{ABC Company, 123 Road Ln, Fancy City, MI 48123, United States}`, which is more space-efficient.

Whatever's going on with the balancing we can force appropriate alignment and spacing by placing the manually-breaked address in a single box inside `\affiliation` as

```
\affiliation{
\parbox[t]{10cm}{
ABC Company\\
123 Road Ln\\
Fancy City, MI 48123\\
United States
}
}
```

[image: Compilation with affiliation placed in a parbox. Multi-line affiliation is appropriately placed and space with respect to title matter.]

If there are also any automatic line breaks this may benefit from some fine-tuning of the width of the box.

Comment: This is a great, simple fix. I've selected the answer by Simon as the solution though because that version has a little bit better line spacing. I like both options though! Thanks very much for your help!